# How to make Totem automatically fit window size to video size?

Tags: 20.04, window, resize, totem

Is it possible to make Totem automatically fit window size to video size (not the other way), like other players do?
It seems that Totem keeps it's window at fixed size and scales the video to fit in window, instead of adjusting window size to video size. I can't see any option in preferences to change this behavior (Ubuntu 20.04).
Last time I was using Totem it was in Ubuntu 10.04, where it behaved as expected ie. window size has been adjusted to video size. Why has this opton been removed? It's illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an issue to Totem: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/-/issues/431 but the developers answer that they don't plan to restore this functionality. So I wrote a simple wrapper script around Totem that needs to be set as a default application to open video files instead of just Totem. Unless the video is very small (which means less than approx. 360 pixels in height, Totem window doesn't want to go so small), it resizes the window to correct video size. The script needs "mediainfo" program to be installed.

```
#!/bin/sh

CFG_DIR=~/.config/totem
CFG_FILE=${CFG_DIR}/state.ini
TMP_FILE=/tmp/_mediainfo.$$

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  if [ ! -d $CFG_DIR ]; then
    mkdir -p $CFG_DIR
  fi
  if [ -f $CFG_FILE ]; then
    MAX=`grep maximised $CFG_FILE`
  else
    MAX="maximised=false"
  fi
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    mediainfo "$1" > $TMP_FILE
    V_WIDTH=`grep '^Width' $TMP_FILE | sed 's/Width.*: //;s/ pix.*$//;s/ //g'`
    V_HEIGHT=`grep '^Height' $TMP_FILE | sed 's/Height.*: //;s/ pix.*$//;s/ //g'`
    # 720x576 videos with 16:9 AR are special
    if [ "$V_WIDTH" = "720" -a "$V_HEIGHT" = "576" ] && { grep '^Display aspect ratio.*: 16:9' $TMP_FILE >/dev/null ; } then
      V_WIDTH=1024
    fi
    echo "[State]" > $CFG_FILE
    echo "window_w=$V_WIDTH" >>$CFG_FILE
    echo "window_h=$V_HEIGHT" >>$CFG_FILE
    echo "${MAX}" >> $CFG_FILE
  fi
fi

totem "$1"
```

**Edit:** the above script has an issue when the file contains more than one video stream. To fix this, add `head -1` at the end of lines starting with `V_WIDTH=` and `V_HEIGHT=`:

```
    V_WIDTH=`grep '^Width' $TMP_FILE | sed 's/Width.*: //;s/ pix.*$//;s/ //g' | head -1`
    V_HEIGHT=`grep '^Height' $TMP_FILE | sed 's/Height.*: //;s/ pix.*$//;s/ //g' | head -1`
```